# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Postgresql Metadata issue

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

We are setting up SCDF on the Kubernetes cluster through kubectl.  We are using PostgreSQL for the Metadata process. We got the set up done, and we can see various tables created in the Postgresql, and we can access SCDF UI, but when we try to add any task or try to import repository, then we are getting this error message :

“could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet “

Did anyone see this error during the installation phase of SCDF?

Comment: Please provide some relevant information (e.g., full stack trace). The `could not extract ResultSet ` could mean many things and could come from many places. What you have provided tells us nothing at all.

Comment: Hi @OlegZhurakousky - Thanks for your response. There was version mismatch issue on the DB Driver.  Sabbyanandan helped me to resolve this issue on the gitter IM. Thanks for your time.